# Jquery inserting html string instead DOM nodes

Tags: jquery, string, dom

I have some nested lists and I want to be able to insert a previous level element:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1
<ul>
<li class="selecteditem">Item 1.1</li>
<li>Item 1.2</li>
<li>Item 1.3</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<!-- language: lang-js -->
//I try to do it as follows:
$('li.selecteditem').after('</ul></li><ul>"...
```

But the after() method only allows to insert DOM nodes, so all the closed tags "" are ignored.
Is there a way to inject this html string literally exactly where I want it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you paste how do you want your html result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you need now, but DOM manipulation can only occur given DOM nodes, or valid markup that can be converted to DOM nodes. What you can do is something like this, although this is a pretty hacky solution:

```
var html = $('ul').html().replace('<li class="selecteditem">Item 1.1</li>','<li class="selecteditem">Item 1.1</li></ul></li><ul>...');
$('ul').html(html);
```

Comment: Yeah, been thinking about this myself  too, that's pretty hacky, but if this is all we have, then it is not that hacky but the right answer...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$('.selecteditem').append('<li>Item 1.4</li>');​
```

If you use `.append()` you insert html to a certain element keeping the html inside it.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/xJDAt/)